# SQL CASE WHEN in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

As the picture shows below,
I want to change SQL Server deliverDay column '0;1;2;3;4' to 'Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday'.
But I don't want to write it as hardcode such as:

```
CASE WHEN deliverDay = '0' THEN 'Monday'
WHEN deliverDay = '0;1' THEN 'Monday;Tuesday'
WHEN deliverDay = '0;1;2' THEN 'Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday'
WHEN deliverDay = '0;1;2;3' THEN 'Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday'
WHEN deliverDay = '0;1;2;3;4' THEN 'Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday'
```

I want to write a SQL to auto change the String "0" to "Monday", "1" to "Tuesday", so that when there is a deliverDay column maybe is '0;3;6', it can auto set the deliverDay column to 'Monday;Thursday;Sunday'.

[image]

Are there any solutions? Appreciate it.

Comment: Try `replace()`. You'll need to nest seven total calls though. Hardcoding would involve 128 cases and I don't remember SQL Server limits on the number it will handle.

Comment: Refer to this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=192095b9af477a5cc3cfd50980dea797)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Use ```SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())``` to get your desire result.

Comment: This is not a good design. You should have a `DeliveryDays` table, with one row for each eligible day, and a foreign key back to your existing table. If you want to concatenate the days into a string to show the data to users, handle that as a query or better yet in the presentation layer.

Comment: Never, ever store data as semicolon separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Answer (score 1):

nested replace().  So the inner-most starts your delivery day column and looks for a 0, changes it to Monday.  After that result, it now falls out to 1 and Tuesday, etc.

If there is no corresponding digit, obviously nothing has to be replaced out

```
select replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( deliveryday
    , '0', 'Monday')
    , '1', 'Tuesday' )
    , '2', 'Wednesday' )
    , '3', 'Thursday' )
    , '4', 'Friday' )
   from ...
```

So if your delivery day value is '0;2;4'
The inner most converts it to 'Monday;2;4'
No value of 1 found, so remains 'Monday;2;4'
2 found so it changes to 'Monday;Wednesday;4'
No value 3 so remains unchanged
Finally finds a 4 and becomes 'Monday;Wednesday;Friday'